# Two-way trustless information sharing?

Tags: security, server, service

In my service structure, I have 3 different entities:

1. A third-party website/service (*not* mine), storing sensitive information of end-users
2. End-users with login information to the aforementioned third-party site
3. My service, who relies on a analyzing accurate (subset of) information from the third-party site.

My service needs to read a certain set of information belonging to the end-user from the 3rd-party-site. In order for it to work, that set of information needs to be accurate.

The easy, but problematic, way of approaching this would simply be to let the end-user pass my service their login credentials for the 3rd-party-service, so that my service can scrape and read the relevant information from there, without having to trust the end-user to provide accurate information.
However, this is problematic, because the end-user has no proof that my service is not storing their credentials or reading more information than it should. This might not be an issue for some part of the userbase, but it makes me unable to provide a guarantee of security, which might matter to another part of the userbase.

The second easy, but probelmatic, way of approaching this would be to let the end-user provide the information, either directly or by having a client-side scraper included in my services front-end, thus assuring the client that none of their information ever goes to my backend.
However, this is problematic, because my service cannot trust the end-user to not spoof the information they pass along.

The best, but impossible, way of approaching this would be to pass along the credentials to the 3rd party service in an encrypted manner. However, that would only work if the 3rd-party-service is prepared for such a usecase, which it isn't.

As such, I have a structure where (1) has needed information, (2) has access to it, but does not want to pass the access to (3), and (3) needs information from (1) but doesn't want to rely on (2) giving it accurately.

In other words, (2) and (3) do not want to trust each other, yet there needs to be some kind of communication to access the information of (1). How could I build my system to accommodate for such a case?

Comment: Could I, perhaps, prompt the user to copy their login cookies? Thus not giving me their credential information? But I just tried manually copying my cookies from one browser in the other, and it didn't log me in, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: This is exactly the usecase supported by OAuth2. If the 3rd party service provides OAuth2, you should use that. You cannot securely implement this without some kind of support by the 3rd party service.

Comment: @GaborLengyel The 3rd party doesn't do anything like that - The only ways of accessing their data is (a) have my users relay it (which would rely on it being the truth, and is thus not a good way), (b) scrape the service client-side, sending the data to my service (which is hackable/spoofable), (c) scrape it from my backend, which however requires the user to fully trust me, which is a situation I also want to avoid. I want to be able to "prove" that my service is fully secure & respects privacy, without having to rely purely on my words.

Comment: This is not possible. It's pretty much the reason why OAuth exists. :)